# NCrunch "no tests are queued for execution"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ncrunch

In Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 3 and with NCrunch 2.15.0.9, my MSTest unit tests do compile (I can run them in MSTest), but NCrunch shows them as

> No tests are queued for execution. Monitoring 2 tests, with no tests ignored

The status of those tests is

> Running (First time run), Prioritized

If they are really running, they never complete. Running them in MSTest only takes milliseconds.

The C# class library is still a very simple project, almost HelloWorld complexity. It does not have any strange dependencies. It is not signed and it does not have pre- or post-build-steps.

I have set my NCrunch configuration with the wizard

- 2/4 cores for NCrunch
- max 1 background processing thread
- optimize for fastest test execution
- run my tests one at a time
- run my tests automatically when changes are detected
- let my tests run - I will ignore them as I need to

The tests don't run even if I manually trigger it.

There is no content in the NCrunch Diagnostic Output window.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I have other plugins installed:

- VisualSVN 5.1.2
- Resharper Ultimate 10.0.1
- OzCode 2.0.0.1029

[image: Screnshot NCrunch Tests not running]

Limitations: I can't upgrade NCrunch, since my license expired.

I have tried:

- Upgrading Resharper Ultimate to 2016.1
- "prevent signing of the output assembly"
- "copy referenced assemblies to workspace"
- set architecture to x86 on both, the DLL and the Tests

Comment: Will your tests run with any other test runner other than MS Test such as ReSharper?

Comment: @JCisar: yes, they will run (and fail) in Resharper

Comment: I know this is a dumb suggestion as I am sure that you have tried it, but sometimes NCrunch gets cached and thus stalls.  Have you tried cleaning, rebuilding and hitting "Resynchronize, rebuild and rerun all tests"?  This is typically what I do when NCrunch is stuck.  This is slightly different than telling it to manually run the tests.

Comment: @JCisar: yes, I tried that, too. I just found a solution: it is related to the new .NET 4.6.1 framework that is the new default in VS 2015 Update 3

Comment: Glad you got it figured out as not having NCruch feels so slow once your are used to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest Visual Studio Update 3 makes .NET 4.6.1 the default .NET Framework for new projects.

Switching both projects (the DLL and the unit tests) back to the slightly older .NET 4.5.2 and then hitting the "Resynchronize, rebuild and rerun" button fixed the problem.

This [may be fixed in newer versions 2.20 of NCrunch](http://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postsm8196_-NET-framework-4-6-1.aspx), but my NCrunch license does even not support .NET 4.6.